# How do I find CI of Mean Response using Python?

Tags: python, statistics

After spending 2 hours of research to no avail, I decided to pose my question here. What is the code to find CI of mean response in python?

I know how to do it in R, but I just don't know what I need to do for Python. I assume statsmodel has a function for that. If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Check `wls_prediction_std` from `statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd`.